# Sitecore media not found for other languages

Tags: sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.1, sitecore-media-library, sitecore8.2

I'm currently working on sitecore and facing an issue where for fetching a media i.e .jpeg or .PDF in English it's opening but for other languages it's not opening and showing in .ashx format in URL however i don't think this is an issue because when we edit URL of english language with .ashx instead of .pdf it still shows the file but not in other languages.
We tried removing the media Request handler value and kept it blank and tried some more past suggestions for the solution but nothing worked for us.
It would be great if anyone can come with a possibility of our solution.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have language fallback enabled for media items ?

Comment: Yes, That's enabled in whole project but for some pdf and images having this problem.